# Retrieve browser session id from Response Headers(selenium)

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

When trying to access `driver.session_id`, I got a session id, that looks to belong to driver's session, not the one from Response Headers. After doing some research it seems that Selenium doesn't allow to get the `session_id`.

Can somebody help with a code snippet (Python).
I've captured the XHR request details, and searched for Session-Id in frontend logs, and found it.

Is there a workaround to get the `sessionId` from response headers? (the actual session id from browser)

Comment: Are your Response headers exposed ?
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Access-Control-Expose-Headers

Comment: Seems the response headers are exposed, since when checking the XHR request i can see the detail headers !

Comment: Yes but potentially not accessible though. You can see them in your request details but not use them if not exposed. 
Try to add this response Header Access-Control-Expose-Headers: session_id